# Download from S3 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I have a single javascript file that I am trying to use to download a text file from one of my S3 buckets. However when I execute this file using "node file.js" nothing happens / gets returned. Is there something wrong here that I should be calling? Thanks!

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'personal-account'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

s3.getObject(
  { Bucket: "mybucket", Key: "testing.txt" },
  function (error, data) {
    if (error != null) {
      alert("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
    } else {
      alert("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");
    }
  }
);

print("this file has been executed")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `print` function in javascript as well as no `alert` in nodejs environment.

So you have to use something like `console.log` instead.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'personal-account'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

s3.getObject(
  { Bucket: "mybucket", Key: "testing.txt" },
  function (error, data) {
    if (error != null) {
      console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
    } else {
      console.log("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");
    }
  }
);

console.log("this file has been executed")
```

But if you don't see any output, even errors, then something is completely wrong with your setup. And it is hard to tell what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Create the S3 Client after setting up your credentials:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'personal-account'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.getObject(
  { Bucket: "mybucket", Key: "testing.txt" },
  function (error, data) {
    if (error != null) {
      console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
    } else {
      console.log("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");
    }
  }
);

console.log("this file has been executed");
```